# Copy chrome browser history from windows to linux?

Tags: windows, linux, google-chrome

How do I copy my old google history from windows vista to fedora? Is moving `user/AppData/Local/Gooogle/Chrome/User Data/Default` to `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` a valid way to do this or is there a 'better' way to do it?

Comment: that's a valid way

Comment: I actually just tried this, and ran into some problems. Chrome wasn't quite behaving as expected (got some 'couldn't load profile' errors or something).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set up synchronization between the two of them. Look under Preferences -> Personal Stuff -> Sync.

Comment: History is not currently synced by chrome.

Comment: True, history is ephemeral anyway. But you can just bookmark what you like from your history and that is synced.